# SQL: Retrieve missing values from superset

Tags: sql, postgresql, cross-join

I have a table like this:

```
Device  | Rating
-----------------
iPhone  | 1
iPhone  | 2
iPhone  | 4
iPhone  | 5
Android | 3
Android | 5
```

I want to return a table with all the ratings possible. In this case `1 to 5`.
So my resulting table will be:

```
Device  | Rating
-----------------
iPhone  | 1
iPhone  | 2
iPhone  | 3
iPhone  | 4
iPhone  | 5
Android | 1
Android | 2
Android | 3
Android | 4
Android | 5
```

I have tried using something like:

```
SELECT a.device, b.rating
FROM device_rating_table a
RIGHT JOIN rating_lookup_table b
ON a.rating = b.rating
GROUP BY 1,2
;
```

but this does not work. Can you please suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cross join` the list of distinct devices with numbers between 1 and 5:

```
select d.device, r.rating
from (select distinct device from mytable) d
cross join generate_series(1, 5) as r(rating)
```

Or if you want to generate the rating range from the minium and maximum values that are in the table:

```
select d.device, r.rating
from (select distinct device from mytable) d
cross join (select generate_series(min(rating), max(rating)) from mytable) as r(rating)
```

Finally: if all the ratings are availabel in the table already, no need to use `generate_series()`:

```
select d.device, r.rating
from (select distinct device from mytable) d
cross join (select distinct rating from mytable) r
```

Comment: Amazing as always! Thank you! Can I pick your brain a little more? Is there an alternative to cross join or recursive cte? Asking because my actual data is >10M rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `with recursive`:

```
with recursive cte as (
  select distinct device d, 1 r from devices
  union all
  select d, r + 1 from cte where r < 5
)
select * from cte order by d asc;
```